# Removing all DataGrid row and cell borders

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I want to hide (or remove) all the borders of all the rows (and subsequently cells) in my datagrid, think a basic [HTML table](http://jsfiddle.net/QSqMt/). I've looked all over and most questions seem to be about styling them and not hiding them.

I've already tried setting the BorderBrush and BorderThickness like so:

```
 <DataGrid.RowStyle>
     <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
         <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
     </Style>
  </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Tried the same for the CellStyle, but no dice, still seeing borders.

Comment: Instead of fighting with it in WPF, if this is on a website, you could just use CSS. Give the DataGrid an ID, and use that in CSS to set borderwidth=0, borderstyle=none, bordercollapse=collapse and so on.

Comment: Not a site, just WPF. The link to the HTML table was merely to illustrate the concept.

Comment: OK, then I guess it isn't an HTML table then.

Comment: Nowhere have I stated I need an actual HTML table, just that I want my WPF datagrid to look like a basic HTML table without borders, hence "think a basic HTML table"

Answer (score 187, accepted):

What about setting `GridLinesVisibility="None"`?

```
<DataGrid GridLinesVisibility="None">
    ...
<DataGrid>
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that, it's exactly what I want! :-)

Comment: in some versions of ASP the attribute is: `<DataGrid GridLines="None">
    ...
<DataGrid>`

Comment: Man i was just about to write a template for DataGridCell when I came across this solution +1

Answer (score 2):

You could also do it this way

```
 dataGrid.GridLinesVisibility = DataGridGridLinesVisibility.None;
```