# C# - Removing right edge row border in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, border, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to remove the far right GridLine in a WPF GridView.
Here is an example .xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Pack.ExampleForm"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Pack"
    Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"
    Width="400" Height="300">

    <DataGrid Margin="5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        CanUserReorderColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="Column">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" CanUserResize="False"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Key}" Header="Request Header" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Value}" Header="Value" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

        <local:RequestHeader Key="Subject 1" Value="Body 1" />
        <local:RequestHeader Key="Subject 1" Value="Body 1" />
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

However this has the far right gridline, as show in the designer, circled in yellow.

[image: Example]

Is there any way to remove this and have no border, as it is on the left side. Would prefer to do this in the .xaml if possible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hm, it is just sneaky workaround, but... :)

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value}" Width="*">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,-1,0"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>    
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Ha!  This has the benefit of not removing the right border, which is nice if the user resizes the columns.

Comment: What is wrong with removing the border? What shall happen on resizing? Why does this not work with BorderThickness instead of margin?

Answer (score 4):

While @monstr's solution *does* work, it feels like an abuse of the Margin property (it could also make tracking down layout issues more difficult later on). Another solution, which is very similar to the ones suggested by @Nick Sologoub and @Xtr but is slightly cleaner, is to use DataGrid's CellStyle property to modify all cell styles associated with that DataGrid along with DataGrid's GridLinesVisibility property.

```
<DataGrid GridLinesVisibility="None">
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,0,0,1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <!--Other DataGrid Items-->
</DataGrid>
```

[image: This picture demonstrates how the proposed code looks.]

By styling cells in this manner, you do not affect the layout of controls (whereas messing with the margin does). You also get the benefit of only affecting this one specific DataGrid, and no others in your application. However, if you *did* want this style to be applied to all DataGrids in your window, you could put it in your window's resources, or even in your application's resources.

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
            <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="None"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,0,0,1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid>
            <!--DataGrid Items-->
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Notice that the GridLinesVisibility property is also included as it is necesary for this solution to work properly.

**The proper way to achieve window/application level styling (like above) would most likely include some usage of ResourceDictionaries, but that's a whole different topic.**

Comment: This is easily the best answer

Comment: your solution just creates a far left border line since u explicitly defined the thickness

Answer (score 1):

IF you want to remove whole Grid cell border then can use **GridLinesVisibility="None"**.
else below is the solution to remove single border.

[Removing all DataGrid row and cell borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810771/removing-all-datagrid-row-and-cell-borders)

Comment: I just want to remove the right gridline border only. The other link doesn't give any information on how to do that, it only refers to removing every border.

Comment: @NickKitto You may not want to remove it entirely, as the user may resize the column to make it smaller, in which case the column header would have a border, but the cells themselves would not.  The answer from monstr cleverly avoids that problem.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research, but it doesn't seem like MSFT exposes the properties to modify each specific grid line. So I have a workaround for you. It's not ideal, but it's quite clean and involves no code-behind.

Basically there is a property to control the visibility of grid lines. What you do is hide the vertical ones and then you create a style for cells that will manually create vertical grid lines. You apply that style to every column except for the last one and you get the design you desire.

```
   <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle">
      <Setter Property="DataGridCell.BorderThickness" Value="0 0 1 0" />
      <Setter Property="DataGridCell.BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="grid" Margin="5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="Column" 
        GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" >
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" CanUserResize="False" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Key}" Header="Request Header" Width="*" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Value}" Header="Value" Width="*"/>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
  </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a style for TextBox customizing **BorderThickness** property (2,2,0,2).

2) Add the style within the last DataGridColumn.

So that the last column's TextBox border alone would result with the required change.

Comment: This didn't have the desired effect. This added 2 px grey borders inside the cell as extra. It did not affect the surrounding black gridline borders.

Answer (score 0):

Without re-templating the whole DataGrid, you could set the DataGrid's GridLinesVisibility to Horizontal and specify a DataGridCell style that changes each cell's border properties.

```
<DataGrid Margin="5"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
          HeadersVisibility="Column"
          GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
          ItemsSource="{Binding SomeDictionary}">
      <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
          <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,0,0,0"/>
          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
        </Style>
      </DataGrid.Resources>
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" CanUserResize="False"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Key}" Header="Request Header" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Value}" Header="Value" Width="*"/>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Then you will only see the actual DataGrid's border, which you can remove with `BorderThickness="1,1,0,1"` on the DataGrid if you want.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have found uses a Grid instead of a DataGrid.  I wrap each cell in a border with a BorderThickness="a,b,c,d" where:

```
a = Left Border
b = Top Border
c = Right Border
d = Bottom Border
```

Any one(s) that I don't want to see get set to 0.
If I use a particular one over and over, I set a Style and reuse that.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help:

[image]

this solved for me edge problem in WPF DataGrid. Just put "0" to RowHeaderWidth property