# Remove header border of a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

How can I remove the grey line which is visible between the `Header` and the `Row` of a `DataGrid`.

[image: Border]

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a different post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27178007/c-sharp-removing-right-edge-row-border-in-wpf-datagrid?lq=1), that should help you with this issue. It explains how to adjust Border width of DataGrid. I believe that is what you are trying to do.

Will changing the column header style help you:

```xml
<DataGridColumn.HeaderStyle>
  <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,0" />
  </Style>
</DataGridColumn.HeaderStyle>
```

Comment: I had seen that post before but unfortunately it didn't work for me.

Comment: Why exactly is it not working? Can you give me an example of your code? I understand what I think you are trying to do, but I need an example of what you have attempted already to see if I can help at all

Comment: you can try <DataGrid GridLinesVisibility="None"> but this will get rid of all your border lines

Comment: I know it. But I need to remove only the border after header.

Comment: What about setting the Header Border thickness?

Comment: I can't remove the border with the thickness property.